# Is there an official repository for snaps?

Tags: snap

> "uApp Explorer is the unofficial viewer for snaps and Ubuntu Touch apps."

If you are looking for snaps on the [official site for snap on ubuntu desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy), the only link you will find, links to the [unofficial viewer](https://uappexplorer.com/). I am confused? Is there no official viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an official repository for snaps?

Yes there is, but it provides only API to interact with. `snap` or Software Center may used to search and install them. See [Click Package Index’s documentation](https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/docs/).

> Is there no official viewer?

<s>If you mean a Web interface to browse the store, then Agree, there is no official yet.</s>

Update: Now, there is one at https://snapcraft.io/store , Thank you [Max](https://askubuntu.com/users/283155/max).

Comment: There seems to be one now https://snapcraft.io/store